# Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3, tag, id3

I need to tag my MP3 library, and have tried kid3 (which was manual tagging), when I used Kubuntu 9.10 (I now use **Ubuntu Meerkat**) Here are the features I am hoping for:

- A good and clean UI.
- Tagging should be automatic, like Winamp's autotag feature, which rocks, btw!
- It should also embed the cover-art in the mp3, not copy a jpeg file in the folder, because now-a-days all players support displaying cover art. But acceptable if not possible.
- Rename the files as per some regular expression like %TrackNo - %Artist - %Title.
- Should be accurate, and more importantly smart. I want to start tagging at night, and hopefully my collection should be done by the morning, w/o it being stuck at a user prompt at 1%.

If one app cant do all, I am willing to use 3, wouldn't mind exposure to a few more apps ;)

I have used picard or someting, and I didnt like it quite a lot. But wouldn't mind using it, if there is no other alternative.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: [Command-line only alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226773/how-to-read-mp3-tags-in-shell)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### [EasyTAG](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/easytag)

You can try EasyTAG, a nice graphical editor for tags in mp3 and aac files.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: yeah, seems good enough, I dont have enough English songs atm, All I have are hindi, and it couldnt tag them properly, I guess freedb doesnt have that info. Winamp uses gracenote, and it has all the info.

Comment: +1 - Good suggestion. It has a few quirks but is the best I've used in GNU/Linux.

Comment: At the program - can I change / copy metadata to **all selected files** from the one being edited? Oh, got it! Right-click selected files and `scaner` option.

Answer (score 16):

### [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload)

i just went over my entire collection 80gigs+, i did a lot of research and tried easytag, banshee, etc the only that really stands out for me was MusicBrainz Picard.

Its very clever, backed up a by a huge database. The scanning functionality is what really impressed me, it plays the song and then makes an audio fingerprint of it. It then compares it to the database and populates all the metadata. neat

Comment: what did u use for the album art?

Comment: The only problem with Picard is that the same track can belong in more than one album release, so if you fingerprint it may associate the track with "greatest hits 1" instead "the best of" so you end up with a muddled collection

Comment: This is a great piece of software!

Answer (score 7):

### [Audio Tag Tool (`tagtool`)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tagtool/)

You can also install [tagtool](http://packages.ubuntu.com/tagtool). This will allow you to edit the ID3 tags of OGG and MP3 files using a nice GUI.

**Warning**: Last update: 2013-04-24

[image: screenshot]

Comment: does it fetch tags from the internet, and maybe covers too?

Comment: @KaustubhP not sure on fetching tags from internet.

Answer (score 5):

For

- automatic tagging, I recommend [Musicbrainz Picard](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet).
- manual tag editing and robust pattern-based file renaming, I recommend [Ex Falso](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet).

I can't recommend anything for you for album art, since I use the "picture in the same folder" method.

Answer (score 4):

### [Puddletag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSOfhQ7UYW4)

You might be interested in using [Puddletag](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSOfhQ7UYW4). It has all the features you mentioned, as well as some more automated %Filename - %Artist - %Title customization.

[image]

Included with puddletag are tag sources supporting lookups from [Amazon, Discogs, FreeDB and MusicBrainz and AcoustID.](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/source/tagsources.html) There is also quite a number of [features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puddletag) this application supports.

Answer (score 4):

### [Beets](http://beets.io/)

You definitively want `beets`:

```
pip install beets
```

config.yaml:

```
plugins: fetchart
paths:
  default: $albumartist/$album%aunique{}/$track - $albumartist - $title
```

```
beet import <directory>
```

... and let the magic happen.

See also [the official getting started](https://beets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/main.html) guide.

Answer (score 2):

Only today I discouvered [MP3 Diags](http://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/index.html). It has a file renamer and a tag editor with Discogs and Musicbrainz support and can parse directory and filenames. Also, it fixes various low level issues.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend amarok or songbird . both are good..

Comment: As of 2016, [Amarok still doesn't show custom ID3v2 tags](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/24620/is-there-a-music-player-for-linux-that-can-sort-based-on-multiple-tags-at-the-sa/35004#35004).

Answer (score 1):

as for me. the only tagger I've used and worked nice is Mp3Tag using wine. Not slow and you can download album details from amazon.com or amazon.de [mp3tag page](http://mp3tag.de) also music brainz and it has a clean UI more focused on tagging. I recommend this than easy tag

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the [zortam online mp3 tagger](http://autotag.zortam.com/applet.php) which can fetch cover arts and lyrics as well. For me it did the job, and it's very accurate. I use Fedora, but normally it should work on any OS if you have Java installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Winamp via Wine? It seems that Winamp works without major problems.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2723&iTestingId=54480