# What software can I use to search for and applying missing tags to my music collection?

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3-tag

Can I search for missing tags with *Musicbrainz Picard* or some other application? My music folder is ~80 GB and I want the application to show me all missing tags (and hopefully fix them by retrieving tag data from freedb or amazon.com).

Comment: You may be interested in using another [MusicBrainz enabled application](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Enabled_Applications) instead. I'm not familiar with any of them, but it looks like there are at least a couple that are designed for scanning large collections.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg yes i am .

Comment: If you are still looking for an application to search for and apply missing tags many are described in the related question: [Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher)

Answer (score 3):

Try **EASY TAG**

It’s a great tool for editing most ID3 tags (both version 1 and 2) on all popular music filetypes.

It automatically taggs music using CDDB and renaming the files themselves and directories they are in

More information can be found here (including reviews):

[image]

Directly install from here:
[Easytag](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/easytag) [image: Install easytag-aac]

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [Kid3](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/kid3-qt):

With Kid3, an audio tag editor you can:

- Edit ID3v1.1 tags in your MP3 files
- Edit all ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 frames in your MP3 files
- Convert between ID3v1.1, ID3v2.3 and ID3v2.4 tags
- Edit Ogg/Vorbis tags
- Edit FLAC tags
- Edit APE tags in MPC files
- Edit tags in MP3, Ogg/Vorbis, FLAC, MPC, MP4/AAC, MP2, Speex, TrueAudio and WavPack files
- Edit tags of multiple files, e.g. the artist, album, year and genre of all files of an album typically have the same values and can be set together
- Generate tags from filenames
- Generate filenames from tags
- Generate playlist files
- Automatic case conversion and string translation
- Import and export album data
- Import from gnudb.org, TrackType.org, MusicBrainz, Discogs

[image]