# Can Audacious music player edit metadata of music?

Tags: 11.10, music-player, audacious

I've been trying to find an alternative to Banshee, and right now, I'm using Clementine. It really is a great music player, but it just has too many features for me. All I listen to are soundtracks from movies and games and such, so all of the extra radio, podcast, lyric finding, etc. stuff is useless.

I've seen that Audacious is an extremely light and fast music player that seems to be simple. I'm going to try it out, but I need one essential thing: A metadata editor built in. I love the fact that Banshee and Clementine both have one, so it makes it extremely easy to edit my music. **Does Audacious have a metadata editor, or no?** I've been trying to find information on their website, but it seems as if their website is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit metadata with Audacious we can open track information from either *Playback -> View track details* or by right click on a track on your playlist. This shows all metadata available. These can be edited and saved (provided you have permissions to do so on the given file)

[image]

If your library contains many tracks that need editing you may be faster using an [external track editor](https://askubuntu.com/q/16036/3940).

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to edit the metadeta of an album like it is in Banshee? There all I have to do is right click on the album and I can change the metadeta for all the music in the album.