# How Can I Edit Songs on a Remote Server?

Tags: 11.10, ssh, music, ftp, music-player

I have a number of songs I am hosting. I would like to edit their ID3 tags.

Downloading and uploading them will take too much time. Is it possible to edit them as they are online?

Update

> Here is the error i got when i tried installing Rhythmbox on the
>   server
>
> Suggested packages:   gconf-defaults-service libbonobo2-bin libdv-bin
>   esound desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra lirc
>   librsvg2-bin sg3-utils python-gnome2-doc python-gobject-dbg
>   python-gst0.10-dev python-gst0.10-dbg   python-gtk2-doc python-numpy
>   python-libxml2-dbg python-pyorbit-dbg gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
>   python-coherence   gnome-codec-install gnome-control-center
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly brasero Recommended packages:
>   libpam-ck-connector esound-clients gnome-media gvfs-backends
>   gnome-keyring libgpod-common   launchpad-integration
>   notification-daemon libvisual-0.4-plugins yelp avahi-daemon The
>   following NEW packages will be installed   consolekit dbus-x11
>   devicekit-disks esound-common gamin gconf2 gnome-icon-theme
>   gnome-media-common   gnome-mime-data gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x gvfs hicolor-icon-theme
>   libaa1 libart-2.0-2 libatasmart4 libaudiofile0 libavahi-glib1
>   libavc1394-0 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common   libbonoboui2-0
>   libbonoboui2-common libbrasero-media0 libcaca0 libcdparanoia0
>   libck-connector0 libcroco3   libdv4 libeggdbus-1-0 libesd-alsa0
>   libffi5 libgail-common libgail18 libgamin0 libgdu0 libglade2-0
>   libgmime-2.4-2 libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-media0 libgnome2-0
>   libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0   libgnomecanvas2-common
>   libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common
>   libgpod4   libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgtk2.0-bin libgudev-1.0-0
>   libgvfscommon0 libhal-storage1 libhal1   libiec61883-0
>   liblaunchpad-integration1 liblircclient0 libmtp8 libmusicbrainz4c2a
>   libnautilus-extension1   libnotify1 libpolkit-agent-1-0
>   libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libproxy0 librsvg2-2
>   librsvg2-common libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsoup-gnome2.4-1
>   libsoup2.4-1 libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a   libtotem-plparser12 libv4l-0
>   libvisual-0.4-0 libwavpack1 libxv1 media-player-info policykit-1
>   policykit-1-gnome python-cairo python-gconf python-gnome2
>   python-gnomecanvas python-gobject python-gst0.10   python-gtk2
>   python-libxml2 python-pyorbit rhythmbox 0 upgraded, 94 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded. Need to get 18.1MB/18.5MB
>   of archives. After this operation, 112MB of additional disk space will
>   be used. Do you want to continue [Y/n]?  WARNING: The following
>   packages cannot be authenticated!   libck-connector0 libeggdbus-1-0
>   libpolkit-gobject-1-0 consolekit dbus-x11 libatasmart4 libgudev-1.0-0 
>   libpolkit-backend-1-0 libsgutils2-2 devicekit-disks esound-common
>   libgamin0 gamin gconf2 hicolor-icon-theme   libgtk2.0-bin libcroco3
>   libgsf-1-common libgsf-1-114 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common
>   gnome-icon-theme   gnome-media-common gnome-mime-data libcdparanoia0
>   libvisual-0.4-0 libxv1 gstreamer0.10-plugins-base libaa1
>   libavc1394-0 libcaca0 libdv4 libhal1 libiec61883-0 libshout3
>   libgnome-keyring0 libproxy0 libsoup2.4-1   libsoup-gnome2.4-1
>   libtag1-vanilla libtag1c2a libv4l-0 libwavpack1
>   gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-x   libgdu0 libavahi-glib1
>   libgvfscommon0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome gvfs
>   libart-2.0-2   libaudiofile0 libbonobo2-common libbonobo2-0
>   libglade2-0 libesd-alsa0 libhal-storage1 libgnomevfs2-common
>   libgnomevfs2-0 libgnome2-common libgnome2-0 libgail18 libgail-common
>   libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomecanvas2-0   libbonoboui2-common
>   libbonoboui2-0 liblaunchpad-integration1 libnautilus-extension1
>   libgmime-2.4-2   libtotem-plparser12 libbrasero-media0 libgnome-media0
>   libgnomeui-common libgnomeui-0 libgpod4 libmtp8   libmusicbrainz4c2a
>   libnotify1 media-player-info python-cairo libffi5 python-gobject
>   python-gconf   python-gnomecanvas python-gtk2 python-pyorbit
>   python-gnome2 python-libxml2 python-gst0.10 liblircclient0   rhythmbox
>   Install these packages without verification [y/N]?  E: Some packages
>   could not be authenticated roland@localhost:~$

Comment: How do you connect to the server?. What kind of server?. Do you have full control of it?.

Comment: I have FTP and SSH access. it is a Linode server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sftp. Just open a Nautilus window, hit CTRL+L, this should show you an address bar, type:

```
ssh://servername/home/yourremoteuser/
```

A window should pop-up asking for your user and password. Give them and you are connected to your server.

Just use any GUI program that you like, it should be able to access the share now, in the left bar of the open window. If for some reason it doesn't (the app doesn't use the standard open dialogs), it will be accessible under *~/.gvfs*.

If you don't know any tagging programs, look at this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher).

Comment: I'm not sure if this won't end in each modified file being download, changed and uploaded again. But it's simpler than the other solutions, so I'd try it first.

Comment: One little question. It says, "Error while saving information. It could not open resource for writing"

Comment: I guess I need write access. I will do that and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Using google I found a nice tool for that: id3ed

You can download it on your server using wget from here:

[id3ed](http://code.fluffytapeworm.com/projects/id3ed)

After that it will look like that:

```
simon@etch:~$ id3ed Gluecklich.mp3 

File Gluecklich.mp3: (tag v1.1)
songname[max:30]: Glücklich
artist[max:30]: Farin Urlaub
album[max:30]: Endlich Urlaub!
year[max:4]: 2001
comment[max:28]: Radio-Mitschnitt
tracknum[max:3]: 0
genre[0-255/name]: Rock
```

Unfortunately I did not find it as a package for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping to access the songs via a GUI. I am not well versed with using terminal to make such changes. Will it not be possible to use an app such as rhythmbox to make the changes?

Comment: In this case just install rhythmbox on the server: sudo apt-get install rhythmbox.This will most likely install A LOT OF software packages (also an X-Server).After that,connect via ssh like that: ssh -X user@host (note the -X). Then run rhythmbox: rhythmbox & - the window will appear on your computer. This is really cool! This requires that you access your server from a linux machine - I dont know if there is a way to get this using a Windows client.

Comment: Hi @Michael K: My guy got an error. it is too long to put here.

Comment: see update for the error that I got.

Comment: execute the command sudo apt-get update and then retry.

Comment: After some twists and turns, I got a new VPS and installed the latest Ubuntu and Rhythmbox. I SSH -X user@host However, I am having problems running RhythmBox as you said. I typed the command  rhythmbox & and it gives me :[1] 8190
root@li278-210:~# Cannot open display: 
Run 'rhythmbox --help' to see a full list of available command line options.