# Alternative to Tag&Rename

Tags: software-recommendation, id3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher)

When I was using windows, I used to use Tag and Rename software for tagging MP3 files, which was really useful and convenient.

Do you have some recommendation to a software which is kind of similar to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Puddletag](http://puddletag.sourceforge.net/) or even [MP3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) in Wine.

[image: PuddleTag screenshot]

Personally I found the latter to be more suited to my tagging needs, but Puddletag is also a quite good alternative.

[image: MP3Tag screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This depends a lot on personal taste because there are quite a few programs to choose from. I use [EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) and am happy with it.