# Any ubuntu tool to edit tag in mp3 files in group

Tags: music, mp3

Is there any tool in ubuntu to edit tag information in mp3 files in group? 
For example, I want to set *all* the files in a directory with the same album name or artists. How can I do that?

I find 'Easytag', but I need to do that 1 file at a time. I want to know if there is something I can do 1 directory/1 directory tree at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a MP3 ID3 tagger, and cover fetcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16036/need-a-mp3-id3-tagger-and-cover-fetcher)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### EasyTAG

Actually with EasyTAG you do not need to set (example) the *Album name* file by file in the same directory.

You can try this:

1. Open the EasyTAG and navigate to the folder you want.
2. Select all the files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Write the Album Name.
4. Click in the checkbox to apply the same Album name to all the selected files.
5. Save the changes to all the selected files.

[image: screenshot]

#### id3tool

Another option could be [id3tool](http://nekohako.xware.cx/id3tool/)

> id3tool is a command line utility for easy manipulation of the ID3
>   tags present in MPEG Layer 3 audio files.
>
> id3tool is a fully GPL'd program. Warm-fuzzy's are 100% optional.

To install it.

```
sudo apt-get install id3tool
```

You can go to your folder eg:

```
cd ~/Music/test-2013/
```

I can list the tags in all the mp3 files with:

```
id3tool *.mp3
```

Example:

```
Filename: 01-track.mp3
Song Title: track1                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album                    
Note:                                   
Track:      1
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)

Filename: 02-track.mp3
Song Title: track2                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album                    
Note:       0                           
Track:      2
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)

Filename: 03-track.mp3
Song Title: track3                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album                    
Note:       0                           
Track:      3
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)
```

I can change the Album Name to all the mp3 files with:

```
id3tool -a Test-Album-id3tool *.mp3
```

Now I have:

```
Filename: 01-track.mp3
Song Title: track1                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album-id3tool            
Note:                                   
Track:      1
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)

Filename: 02-track.mp3
Song Title: track2                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album-id3tool            
Note:       0                           
Track:      2
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)

Filename: 03-track.mp3
Song Title: track3                        
Artist:     Test-Artist                   
Album:      Test-Album-id3tool            
Note:       0                           
Track:      3
Year:       2013
Genre:      Jazz (0x8)
```

**NOTE:** *with the option -a id3tool set the Album Name.*

[Man Pages id3tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/id3tool.1.html)

Comment: There is no checkbox (step 4) for me :/

Comment: @MortezaZiaeemehr there is now a little "ABC" icon in the corner of each field that acts as a checkbox I think. You select all files, fill out the field and click on that icon to apply change too all files you have selected. Spent 20 minutes looking for it.

Answer (score 7):

Without installation, you may use rhythmbox to do it
open the file with rhythmbox and right click > Properties and then do it

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think id3tool only edits id3v1 tags. Most media players now display id3v2 tags. There is a tool for this too.

```
sudo apt-get install id3v2
```

This worked for me.

Comment: ditto. after using id3tool, I had an issue where some mp3s were categorized correctly, and others were not.  id3v2 got them all.

Comment: Yep this worked for fixing cmus display issues whereas id3tool didn't!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `id3v2` instead `id3tool` but there is also one great tool:

```
eyeD3
```

that seems to be more updated, advanced and verbose, but super easy basic to use.

Warning: `eyeD3` uses by default ID3 v 2.4 so if you want to use it with id3v2 you should convert for version 2.3

```
eyeD3 --to-v2.3 *
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3z30hm/id3v2_and_eyed3_tagging_and_listing_tags_v1_v2/):

Listing tags comparison

## eyeD3

List tags

```
eyeD3 *
```

Edit artist

```
eyeD3 -a Name *
```

## id3v2

List tags

```
id3v2 -l *
```

Edit artist

```
id3v2 -a Name *
```