# Cmus not changing displayed artist name after updating metadata

Tags: music, cmus

OCD: Moosh & Twist recently came out with a new album. When I add it to my cmus library, it shows the artist as "Moosh & Twist". Their other albums display properly as "OCD: Moosh & Twist" I figured this was a simple id3tag issue so I used this answer [Any ubuntu tool to edit tag in mp3 files in group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349163/any-ubuntu-tool-to-edit-tag-in-mp3-files-in-group) and ran

```
id3tool --set-artist=OCD:\ Moosh\ and\ Twist *.mp3
```

and now when I run

```
id3tool *.mp3
```

it shows the correct artist name.

I cleared my cmus library and re-added everything, but the new album still shows up as 'Moosh & Twist' despite the Artist id3tag changing.

I am not sure how to get cmus to update the display name properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ended up being a really simple issue. I updated the id3tag, but did not clear the cmus cache so it did not know the data had been updating.

To fix this I ran
`:update-cache` within cmus which reloaded any changed id3tags.

An alternative is to delete the cache and then add everything to your library again.

Answer (score 0):

remove `/home/ur_username/.config/cmus/cache`